# Unable to install Xamarin live on Enterprise preview and Apple SDK on Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to install Xamarin live on my machine. I followed guide but it's not working and I have no idea why.

I know it doesn't work on enterprise yet but  i have the same issue  which is i'm unable to install Apple SDK on both.
I get this error when i try to install Apple SDK in enterprise 2017

```
   19/07/2017 04:16:11 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
    19/07/2017 04:16:11 PM - -------------------------------------------
    19/07/2017 04:16:11 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
    19/07/2017 04:16:11 PM - 15.0.26430.16 built by: D15SVC
    19/07/2017 04:16:11 PM - -------------------------------------------
    19/07/2017 04:16:11 PM - Command line parameters:
    19/07/2017 04:16:11 PM - D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Enterprise,/skuVersion:15.0.26430.16,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017,C:\Users\Mohamed Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXktmlndjx.vsix,/installas:2136,/callingprocessid:5428
    19/07/2017 04:16:11 PM - -------------------------------------------
    19/07/2017 04:16:11 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
    19/07/2017 04:16:11 PM - -------------------------------------------
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM - Initializing Install...
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM - Extension Details...
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM -    Identifier         : Xamarin.VisualStudio.Apple.Sdk
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM -    Name               : Xamarin.Apple SDK
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM -    Author             : Xamarin
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM -    Version            : 4.6.0.328
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM -    Description        : Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM -    Locale             : en-US
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM -    MoreInfoURL        : 
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM -    InstalledByMSI     : False
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM -    SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
    19/07/2017 04:16:12 PM - 
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -    SignatureState     : ValidSignature
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -    SignedBy           : Xamarin Inc.
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -    Certificate Info   : 
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        -------------------------------------------------------
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        [Subject]       : CN=Xamarin Inc., O=Xamarin Inc., L=San Francisco, S=California, C=US
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        [Issuer]        : CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        [Serial Number] : 03914F49E6A72671C7EC48C7D5822184
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        [Not Before]    : 05/01/2017 12:00:00 AM
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        [Not After]     : 10/01/2018 12:00:00 PM
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        [Thumbprint]    : 019BDF9DD8C9230BDE5365B34CE9F9B04DE16121
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - 
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -    Supported Products : 
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -            Version : [15.0,16.0)
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - 
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -    References         : 
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -    Prerequisites      : 
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        -------------------------------------------------------
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        Name         : Visual Studio core editor
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -        Version      : [15.0,16.0)
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - 
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - Signature Details...
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM -    Extension is signed with a valid signature.
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - 
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: Looking for master PkgDef file, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\master.pkgdef

    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: Creating PkgDefCacheNonVolatile
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: Double-checking master pkgdef file
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefManagement initialized
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: RootFolder, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\

    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: ShellFolder, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\

    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefSearchPath, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions;D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef

    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: ImageManifestSearchPath, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions;D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Users\Mohamed Ali\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_61927b39\Extensions

    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: ApplicationExtensionsFolder, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions

    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: "ZeroImpact" = dword:0, "MergeRegistry" = dword:3
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: User extensions enabled by setting, Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_61927b39\ExtensionManager\EnableAdminExtensions

    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefCache flags, PKGDEF: 7001
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDef cache is current.
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefManagement startup complete
    19/07/2017 04:16:23 PM - The extension with ID 'Xamarin.VisualStudio.Apple.Sdk' is not installed to Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017.
    19/07/2017 04:16:30 PM - The following target products have been selected...
    19/07/2017 04:16:30 PM -    Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
    19/07/2017 04:16:30 PM - 
    19/07/2017 04:16:30 PM - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017...
    19/07/2017 04:16:30 PM - VSIX TaskScheduler: VSIX Auto Updatetask already exists.
    19/07/2017 04:16:35 PM - Install Error : System.InvalidOperationException: The VSIX's catalog does not include a 'Component' which is required for install/uninstall.
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetVsVersion)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetVsVersion)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

and I get this error  when i try to do the same thing in enterprise 2017 preview (which is what I need right now)

```
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - -------------------------------------------
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - 15.0.387+g0023a91801
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - -------------------------------------------
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - Command line parameters:
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Enterprise,/skuVersion:15.0.26711.1,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017,/culture:en-US,C:\Users\Mohamed Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIXldunya4t.vsix,/installas:3432,/callingprocessid:3516
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - -------------------------------------------
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - -------------------------------------------
19/07/2017 04:11:27 PM - Initializing Install...
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM - Extension Details...
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM -    Identifier         : Xamarin.Apple.Sdk
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM -    Name               : Xamarin.Apple SDK
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM -    Author             : Xamarin
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM -    Version            : 10.10.0.26
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM -    Description        : Xamarin.iOS SDK
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM -    Locale             : en-US
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM -    MoreInfoURL        : 
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM -    InstalledByMSI     : False
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM -    SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
19/07/2017 04:11:28 PM - 
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -    SignatureState     : ValidSignature
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -    SignedBy           : Xamarin Inc.
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -    Certificate Info   : 
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        -------------------------------------------------------
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        [Subject]       : CN=Xamarin Inc., O=Xamarin Inc., L=San Francisco, S=California, C=US
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        [Issuer]        : CN=DigiCert SHA2 Assured ID Code Signing CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        [Serial Number] : 03914F49E6A72671C7EC48C7D5822184
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        [Not Before]    : 05/01/2017 12:00:00 AM
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        [Not After]     : 10/01/2018 12:00:00 PM
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        [Thumbprint]    : 019BDF9DD8C9230BDE5365B34CE9F9B04DE16121
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - 
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -    Supported Products : 
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -            Version : [15.0,16.0)
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - 
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -    References         : 
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -    Prerequisites      : 
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        -------------------------------------------------------
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        Name         : Visual Studio core editor
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -        Version      : [15.0,16.0)
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - 
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - Signature Details...
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM -    Extension is signed with a valid signature.
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - 
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: Looking for master PkgDef file, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\master.pkgdef

19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: Creating PkgDefCacheNonVolatile
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: Double-checking master pkgdef file
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefManagement initialized
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: RootFolder, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\

19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: ShellFolder, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\

19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefSearchPath, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions;D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef

19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: ImageManifestSearchPath, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions;D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Users\Mohamed Ali\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_8e96ad67\Extensions

19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: ApplicationExtensionsFolder, Path: D:\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions

19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: "ZeroImpact" = dword:0, "MergeRegistry" = dword:3
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: User extensions enabled by setting, Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_8e96ad67\ExtensionManager\EnableAdminExtensions

19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefCache flags, PKGDEF: 7001
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDef cache is current.
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefManagement startup complete
19/07/2017 04:11:39 PM - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
..........  etc
...............


19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\VC\NavigateTo\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\VC\Editor\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\UniversalFlavor\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TypeScript\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TestWindow\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TemplateProviders\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ReferenceManager\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\RazorLanguageServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Project\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ProductUpdate\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ProductUpdate\Windows_VSTools\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Performance Tools\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\OpenFolder\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\NuGet\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\MDD\iOS\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\MDD\Android\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\LiveUnitTesting\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\LanguageServicesNext\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\LanguageServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\InteractiveComponents\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\ExpressionEvaluators\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Language\GenerateType\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Language\CallHierarchy\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\InteractiveWindow\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\FSharp\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ExtensionManager\ServiceModule\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ErrorList\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Editor\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Diff\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\DesignTools\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CMake\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ClientDiagnostics\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ClientDiagnostics\AppResponsiveness\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ClientDiagnostics\AppAnalysis\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\Solution\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\ProgressiveReveal\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\NativeProgressiveReveal\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\NativeCode\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\NativeBinary\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\ManagedProvider\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\LayerDsl\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\Core\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\AssemblyMetadata\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\Analyzers\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\GraphProviderPackage\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\AnalyzeCodeCoverage\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'D:\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\PREVIEW\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\DataDesign\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'C:\USERS\MOHAMED ALI\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_8E96AD67\EXTENSIONS\ydjtl00e.y0s\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'C:\USERS\MOHAMED ALI\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_8E96AD67\EXTENSIONS\uelzsyvp.ukd\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'C:\USERS\MOHAMED ALI\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_8E96AD67\EXTENSIONS\JetBrains\ReSharperPlatformVs15\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\Desktop SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\SDK ARM Additions\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\10\Windows Store SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\8.1\Desktop SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Store SDK\extension.vsixmanifest'
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Skipping 'C:\Users\Mohamed Ali\AppData\Local\Microsoft SDKs' as it doesn't exist
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017...
19/07/2017 04:11:43 PM - VSIX TaskScheduler: VSIX Auto Updatetask already exists.
19/07/2017 04:11:57 PM - Install Error : System.InvalidOperationException: A value for 'Component' needs to be specified in the catalog.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.PackageInstaller.LoadComponent(IDependencyGraph dGraph, Boolean& isProductComponent)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, Version targetedVsVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

Then I get this error when i close installer:

```
The VSIX's catalog does not include a 'Component' which is required for install/uninstall.
```

Comment: Hello Ali, I think the topic of this question would be more appropriate on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) which belong to the stackexange community.

Comment: Okay thanks but i'm not sure. I've already found many topics like that here before posting using google, just try search unable to install xxx on this site.

Comment: @Ali Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet otherwise i'd post an answer here

Comment: it's fixed now @WessamElMahdy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Live Player is unable to be installed with the current preview versions. This is being resolved and will be available as an update soon.

The error you are seeing is related to installing the preview of Xamarin.iOS, which is not needed for the Live Player. However, that is still an issue and I filed it here to be tracked: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58443